# Multiple print output, printing only one of them

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

New to python. So I am running this script, where for an mp3 file is heard(listening api) and the script return the metadata(artist,track name) for that file, with varying confidence percentages.

Code snippet:

```
first = True
for score, rid, title, artist in results:
    if first:
        first = False
    else:
        print()
    cursor.execute("update sc_download set Artist_name=%s , Song_name=%s , MB_ID=%s , Match_Percent=%s where SC_TID=%s" , (artist.encode('utf-8'), title.encode('utf-8'), rid, score*100, track_id))
    conn.commit()
    print('%s\n%s' % (artist, title))
    print('%s' % rid)
    print('%i%%' % (int(score*100)))
```

The problem is, I have around 3-4 outputs, with the highest percentage being around 90% and the lowest being 50%. I am also, inserting this data in mysql, and by default, the last output(with lower percentage) is being written.

The output :

Lana Del Rey
Summertime Sadness (Cedric Gervais remix)
f85d4c4d-20e0-4cdc-a443-45fd5eaeffdc
91%

Lana Del Rey
Summertime Sadness (Cedric Gervais remix)
14aa03d7-3923-45df-b0e3-8ff72b94fc10
69%

Any way to capture only the first output and insert that into the databse?

Aplogies for any lack of clarity, unintentional.

Comment: If you don't want the last output inserted into your database, just... Don't insert the last output into your database.

Comment: Could you please provide some more of the code that you already have? Also, are you trying to capture the data from the print statements in another program, or are you just trying to store `artist` and `title` in a database?

Comment: Do you have control over the script/program that is inserting into the DB?

Comment: Yes, I am just storing the artist and title in the database. Editing the post with more code.

Comment: Yes I am using pymysql to insert it, so I can control it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) For simplicity, get rid of that if at the top of your loop.  Move the print statement to the line before the loop.

(2) If you want only the one result, then don't loop through all of them.  Grab the first and deal with that one alone.  Specifically, trade in your for command for

```
score, rid, title, artist = results[0]
```

Then continue with the rest of your code.